# How to upgrade MySQL in MariaDB 10.2.6

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, mariadb

I were install MariaDB on Macbook using `brew`.

In `brew` web site. They told.

> MariaDB 10.2 is the current stable release of MariaDB. It is built on
>   MariaDB 10.1 with features from MySQL 5.6 & 5.7, and entirely new
>   features not found anywhere else.

But when I install and connect with Sequel Pro. On top of program. It show

> (MySQL 5.5.5-10.2.6-MariaDB)

I want to make `MySQL` version to `5.7`, Because I want to use `JSON` column.

How can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have got the right version, it is 10.2.6. The prefix `5.5.5` is not to worry about, you can ignore it.

It was [added in 10.x versions](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-4088) to allow communicating with old or non-compliant servers/clients/applications which check the version number and refuse to communicate if it's not 5.x.

MariaDB clients strip the prefix, but third-party ones sometimes don't.

That said, please note that MariaDB 10.2.6 does not have JSON *column type*. It has all the same [JSON **functions**](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json-functions/) as MySQL 5.7, and a few more, but there is no **type**, you cannot say `CREATE TABLE t (j JSON)`. The values are supposed to be stored in a regular `TEXT`/`BLOB` column.

Comment: do you think that adding JSON is on MariaDB's roadmap?

Comment: There has been a discussion of a lightweight solution that would provide syntax compatibility for DDL statements like above, without deep internal changes. What for the actual full-blown JSON type, there is an open task about it ([MDEV-9144](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9144)), but it it's not yet on a roadmap, and it hasn't been decided whether it's going to be implemented. My guess is, it will depend on whether there is actual demand.

Comment: There seems to be a moderate number of users using Oracle's JSON, but perhaps not enough to warrant urgent inclusion into MariaDB.  It does put another chink in the "drop-in replacement" claim.

Comment: This claim has been outdated for long time anyway, ever since 5.5, and needs to be revised. The tag info here should be updated, too (and will be soon)..

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#version) says:

> version
>
> Description: Server version number.  It may also include a
>   suffix with configuration or build information.
>   [...] 
>   From MariaDB 10.2.1, this variable can be set at startup  in order to
>   fake the server version.

If left at its default value, old clients will be presented with a compatible InnoDB version number (e.g.: `5.5.5`) despite the variable is internally different:

```
root@host:~# mysql 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 180
Server version: 5.5.5-10.2.13-MariaDB-10.2.13+maria~xenial-log mariadb.org binary distribution

[...]

mysql> show variables like 'version';
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                    |
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
| version       | 10.2.13-MariaDB-10.2.13+maria~xenial-log |
+---------------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

[...]

mysql> show variables like 'innodb_version';
+----------------+--------+
| Variable_name  | Value  |
+----------------+--------+
| innodb_version | 5.7.21 |
+----------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In order to force the version shown to the clients, add this to the `[mariadb]` section of the server's configuration file:

```
[mariadb]
version                 = 5.7.21-10.2.13-MariaDB-10.2.13+maria~xenial-log
```

The output should be as follows:

```
root@host:~# mysql 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 40
Server version: 5.7.21-10.2.13-MariaDB-10.2.13+maria~xenial-log mariadb.org binary distribution

[...]

mysql> show variables like 'version';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                           |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| version       | 5.7.21-10.2.13-MariaDB-10.2.13+maria~xenial-log |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```